# Extract substring from a string until finds a comma

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string

I'm building a page and would like to know how to extract substring from a string until finds a comma in ASP.Net C#. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 41):

```
substring = str.Split(',')[0];
```

If str doesn't contain any commas, substring will be the same as str.

EDIT: as with most things, performance of this will vary for edge cases. If there are lots and lots of commas, this will create lots of String instances on the heap that won't be used. If it is a 5000 character string with a comma near the start, the IndexOf+Substring method will perform much better. However, for reasonably small strings this method will work fine.

Comment: Yes, the key is not needing to check anything.

Comment: Note that this is incredibly inefficient for large strings that contain a comma near their beginning. `String.IndexOf` will stop when it finds the first comma. `String.Split` will always go through the _entire_ string. Consider "Hello, world! I have a very long tale to tell you." + [6000 more characters] + "Hope you enjoyed it!". That's a huge slowdown factor you have there.

Comment: Does anyone care about CPU & memory waste instead of just looking for code 'beauty' !!!!
If a user provides a string like "-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-..." , it would generate an array with a lot of String instances, each containing the single char "-".

Comment: Indeed, the sheer amount of possible allocations is another performance problem.

Comment: There are many potential performance pitfalls, correct. But if and how severely will the code suffer from them depend heavily on usage, so while I totally agree with mentioning the problems, I wouldn't discard it as a valid solution right outfront. All that summed to the fact that, given the comment of the OP below in the answer to dove, [s]he actually wants to use Split. :-)

Comment: It's .split() (case sensitive)

Answer (score 13):

```
var firstPart = str.Split(new [] { ',' }, 2)[0]
```

Second parameter tells maximum number of parts. Specifying 2 ensures performance is fine even if there are lots and lots of commas.

Comment: Good answer but the format is not correct (at least in .NET 4.0).  .Split requires a char array in this case.  i.e.  `var firstPart = str.Split(new char[] { '{' }, 2);`

Comment: @Grax thanks, I've fixed that. FYI, you don't need `char`, compiler will infer array type for you.

Answer (score 10):

You can use IndexOf() to find out where is the comma, and then extract the substring. If you are sure it will always have the comma you can skip the check.

```
        string a = "asdkjafjksdlfm,dsklfmdkslfmdkslmfksd";
        int comma = a.IndexOf(',');
        string b = a;
        if (comma != -1)
        {
            b = a.Substring(0, comma);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Answer (score 9):

```
myString = myString.Substring(0,myString.IndexOf(','));
```

Comment: shouldn't that be myString.IndexOf ?

Comment: It will also throw an ArgumentOutOfRange exception if the string contains no comma.

Comment: I'm leading him down the right path, not writing the entire solution for him!

Comment: And I'm completing your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Alina, based on what you wrote above, then Split will work for you.

```
string[] a = comment.Split(',');
```

Given your example string, then a[0] = "aaa", a[1] = "bbbbb", a[2] = "cccc", and a[3] = "dddd"

Answer (score 3):

```
string NoComma = "";
string example = "text before first comma, more stuff and another comma, there";
string result = example.IndexOf(',') == 0 ? NoComma  : example.Split(',')[0];
```

Comment: Why not just use example.Split(',')[0] by itself?

Comment: @thecoop this would be if you wanted control over what to result if there was no comma in the example, question wasn't explicit on this.  amazing how much variance you can get on the most trivial of requirements...

Comment: thanks, how can i do with multiple commas? I want to save all the words between the commas.

Alina

Comment: @alina string[] results = example.Split(',');  again you need to decide how to deal with edge cases, e.g. no commas, comma as first char, etc